# What's the difference between using parameters and no parameters in brackets of a method

Tags: java

What's the difference between:

1)

```
public void Angle(double f_angle) 
{
    if (f_angle <= 15 && f_Angle >= -15)
    {
        fAngle = 1000 * f_Angle * Math.PI / 180000;
    } else
        system.out.println("Firing Angle: " + f_Angle + " is not between -15 and 15.");
```

**AND**

2)

```
public static int f_angle

public void Angle() 
{ ;
    if (f_angle <= 15 && f_Angle >= -15)
    {
        fAngle = 1000 * f_Angle * Math.PI / 180000;
    } else
        system.out.println("Firing Angle: " + f_Angle + " is not between -15 and 15.");
```

Comment: The difference is whether the method takes parameters or not.

Comment: Do you know the difference between global and local variables? Because that is what this seems to come down to.

Comment: judging by your previous question, you need to read the basic java tutorials

Comment: Also, methods should begin with lowercase letters and variable names should use _camelCase_ in stead of underscores.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in thread safety and convenience:

- You can successfully call the first method concurrently from multiple threads; that's not possible with the second method.
- It is clear to the caller that `f_angle` is method's parameter; there is no such clarity for the second method.

Comment: not just safety, but also correctness. Who knows what method is changing global variable or what they are using it for. (The when bit is the thread safety, obviously)

Comment: do you mean that the second method can probably accept any value unlike the first which can only accept an int value? is it only for user safety?

Comment: @treppenwitz No, that's not what I mean at all. Java lets you run several functions at once (on computers with multiple processors or multiple cores, that's very important). In cases like that, two different methods could call `Angle` at the same time - literally. It is not possible to set `f_angle` to two different values at the same time, so the second method cannot be used, while the first method would do OK.

Comment: @treppenwitz Look up [thread safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) and [reentrancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)).

Answer (score 0):

The parameters add to the method signature. Even though the names are same they are different methods, since their signature is different. That way you can create overloaded methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [method Overloading](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=284)

methods usually are overloaded either to increase the specificity of an operation or to give the caller more flexibility in controlling how the method operates.

Answer (score 0):

*Example #2* operates on a variable in the class that implements the method named *Angle* (which should begin with a lowercase letter).

*Example #1* operates on the parameter that is passed to the *Angle* method from somewhere.

As @dasblinkenlight has pointed out, this has implications regarding thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

What I see as an answer to your question is the difference between local and global variables; which are differentiated by the variable **life time** and the **scope**.

When you define a parameter for a function it acts like a local variable,that once the function is done executing the variable is destroyed(Example #1). And the variable scope is limited to the function block only.

But global variables (Example #2) exists even if the function is finished executing and it is accessible by all the functions.

Comment: so I won't be able to use the variable f_angle in case 1 outside the block?

Comment: you can't. It behaves as same as a local variable declared _inside_ the function.